# getting a specific number from a line in a file mixed with strings in python

Tags: python, search, integer

I have a file in which among other lines there are certain lines which start are like as follows

```
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=EB1, MATERIAL=Alu
*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=EB42, MATERIAL=Alu
....
....
```

Their distinct feature being starting with *SOLID
I would like to get the number in the same line after EB so first iteration should give 1 and second should give 42

what I used is

```
for line in inputFile:
 if line.startswith('*SOLID'):
  trial=line 
  array = line.split(' ')
  target= array[2]
  ID=target[-2:]
  print ID
```

it would give me 1, and 2, as output. I can of-course increase the -2 to -3 but the comma would still be there and when I have 1 or any number less than 10 as the last number it would also include B with that. Any suggestions to this? I could also use ',' as delimiter for the problem of separation of number from alphabet would remain!

Comment: You can use a regex as well: `re.findall('=EB(\d+)', s)[0]`

Comment: @Hamad regex is the most used module for matching, finding etc., try the page https://regex101.com/ for training and usage understanding

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I do not want a complete list directly,  I just need the data for each line as I am trying to extend my model line by line! I already have a complete list of these numbers

Comment: @HamadHassan I don't understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I want to get that number and the parse that number to another file depending on its value! So I donot want to get all the numbers in the file after EB as a list directly, I want to get the output line by line! so that I can use that individually and directly.

Comment: @MarounMaroun besides what is re? on which you are invoking findall?

Comment: @HamadHassan It's a [Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: @HamadHassan `s` is a line, not the whole file. You can still get what you want.

Comment: @MarounMaroun : NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: @HamadHassan Please read the docs, you need to `import re`.

Answer (score 0):

1st, get the needed column with split then get the number with regex

```
import re
line = '*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=EB1, MATERIAL=Alu'
id = line.split()[2].split('=')[-1] # this get EB1
id = re.search('\d+', id).group()   # this get 1
```

or using regex alone

```
import re
line = '*SOLID SECTION, ELSET=EB1, MATERIAL=Alu'
id = re.search('(\S+\s+){2}\w+\=\w*(\d+)', line).group(2) # this get 1
```